# Cannot find the sysmail_mailitems table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-table

Could not find the table  sysmail_mailitems in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Can you help me find that table?

Answer (score 3):

This table is in the msdb database.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems;
```

Comment: i tried your query  but it is giving the srror message "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysmail_mailitems', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'."

Comment: so is that problem with granting access to system tables.do i need ask dba reg this.

Comment: Yes, the dba will need to grant access. However I've been using database mail since SQL Server 2005 and don't recall ever having to go snooping in this table manually - what are you looking for exactly? Could what you're looking for be easier to find in the database mail log?

Comment: actually iam using the stored procedure " sp_send_email" is not sending email.can you please help me.

Comment: Is there a particular error message that occurs? Did you create a valid profile? Are you using the profile when calling the procedure? Did you *test* the profile? What SMTP server has the account been set to use? Does it allow traffic? What appears in the database mail log (you may have to ask your DBA for that as well, but it is in Object Explorer > Management > right-click Database Mail > View Database Mail Log)? I suggest you create a new question and have these answers as part of the question. Nobody is going to be able to solve "is not sending email" without prodding you for more details.